# How Can I make this javascript code cleaner? Reuse variables

Tags: javascript

I am fairly new to Javascript.I have to count some values and my current vairable looks like this :

```
  var mainObj : {  
   "main1":{  
      "var1":0,
      "var2":0,
      "var3":0
   },
   "main2":{  
      "var1":0,
      "var2":0,
      "var3":0
   },
   "main3":{  
      "var1":0,
      "var2":0,
      "var3":0
   }
}
```

Is there a way i can reuse a single object for all that?
Something like :

```
var mainObj :{  
   "main1":{  
      someOBjInstance
   },
,
   "main2":{  
      someOBjInstance
   }   "main3":{  
      someOBjInstance
   }
   }
```

Comment: Questions like this are more suited for [codereview.se].

Comment: belongs to codereview stack exchange

Comment: @Ramanlfc why do you think that? If the list of var goes to 10, would it not make sense to reuse some variable?

Comment: We cannot really help you because you have not specified what operations will you be doing on the main object.

Comment: @Sulthan I would just like to increment the of var1 var2 etc.

Comment: Just use an array for the value of main1 etc, and [increase the values based on their position: `obj.main1[0] = 1`](http://jsfiddle.net/btycaecv/).

Answer (score 1):

It is just a matter of creating copies of the object:

```
var subObject = {
    "var1":0,
    "var2":0,
    "var3":0
};

var mainObj = { 
    "main1": subObject,
    "main2": Object.create(subObject),
    "main3": Object.create(subObject)
};
```

If the values are just a bunch of numbers which you want to increment, then you could use arrays instead of Object, which will be faster and easier to manipulate:

```
var mainArray = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
```